# MQ series conexión setear timeOut C#

Tags: c#, websphere-mq

Estoy creando una conexión a MQ series 8:

```
 try{
    MQEnvironment.Hostname = "xxx";
    MQEnvironment.Channel = "xxx";
    MQEnvironment.Port = 111;
    MQEnvironment.properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);

    MQQueueManager mqmm = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName);

} catch(Exception e){ 
    Console.WriteLine("Error : "+e);
}
```

¿Como prodría setear el `timeOut` a esta conexión?

Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Analizando el articulo

[.NET IBM MQ Series Adapter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34779/NET-IBM-MQ-Series-Adapter)

veo que define un timeout cuando usa

```
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
//otras propiedades
gmo.WaitInterval = pollingTimeout;
```

quizas deberias analizar la clase [MQGetMessageOptions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111200_.htm)

Comment: Gracias pro la respuesta, pero si te das cuenta lo que necesito es colocar timeOut a la hora de realizar al conexión al gestor de colas, el timeOut para el envió de mensajes no es lo que necesito en el momento, ya que esto va después de realizado la conexión al gestor de colas.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible configurarlo en:

- Archivo de configuración del cliente MQ Series, `mqclient.ini`
- Archivo de configuracón de la aplicación .Netm, `app.config`

El parámetro a cambiar en ambos archivos es el `Connect_Timeout`.

Referencias:

- [Esta pregunta hecha en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154830/mq-connection-timeout-c-sharp), respondida por [Sashi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/933250/shashi).
- [MQ Series - Configuring a client using a configuration file](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016840_.htm)
- [MQ Series - Configuring a client using a configuration file - TCP Stanza](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016910_.htm)